# Average and dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba, average

I am trying to calculate averages of a dynamic range. Right now my range is fixed. The part that I want to have as a dynamic value is the `-4`.

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-4]C:R[-1]C)"
```

So in cell B1 it says for example 4 so I tried;

```
j= Range("B1").value 
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-j]C:R[-1]C)"
```

This is of course not working, however I'm new to this all so if anyone knows if this is even possible and how, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vba needs to be outside the quotes and concatenated:

```
j= Range("B1").value 
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-" & j & "]C:R[-1]C)"
```